What is Broardcom AI Accelerator actually?
It seems unclear what it is. NVIDIA GPU (since the use by Alexnet) is to run math (especially matrix) calculations in parallel which reduce the training/inference time. It is about pallalization to reduce time.
Then what is this Broadcom AI accelerator? It looks more of network connectors not providing parallelised math calculation. Is it to move data faster among GPUs and enable distributed training?
